# Запланированный вызов функции и дублирование ответа бота в ВКонтакте

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, бот

мне нужно через бота каждое утро в 8 часов вызывать функцию prizyv_morning(), но я не понимаю что вписать в peer_id чтобы он отправил в айди всех бесед содержащихся в массиве ids_groups. Выводит ошибку

```
__call__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Вот функция которую я хочу запустить и планировщик ниже.

```
    members = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(
        peer_id = "Тут должен быть айди беседы, но я вписывал peer",
    )['items']

    members_ids = [member['member_id'] for member in members if member['member_id'] > 0]

    message = 'Доброе утро! Напоминаю вам что сегодня будет вебинар. Всем хорошего дня!!!'
    for member_id in members_ids:
        message += f'[id{member_id}|#]'
    for i in range(len(ids_group)):
        send_message(ids_group[i], message)

# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////// КОНЕЦ ФУНКЦИЙ ПРИЗЫВА /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////





# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Планировщик по воскресеньям /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

# теги: rus, eng, phys, bio, history, obsch
# ЧАСОВОЙ ПОЯС -3
def scheduler():
    schedule.every().tuesday.at("01:05").do(prizyv_morning)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        sleep(1)  # Выберите оптимальное значение под свои задачи планировщика

# Создаём и запускаем планировщик в отдельном потоке
t = Thread(target=scheduler)
t.start()


# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Конец планировщика /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Также когда я пишу слово круто он дублируется и пишется дважды, должно один раз ответить. Не пойму в чем проблема, Вот весь код:

```
NAME = 'БОТ JASON'
VERSION = 2.0
# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////// ИМПОРТ МОДУЛЕЙ /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
from vk_api import VkApi
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
import schedule
import time
# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////// КОНЕЦ ИМПОРТА МОДУЛЕЙ /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////// МАССИВЫ С ID БЕСЕД И УЧИТЕЛЕЙ /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
ids_group = [ # Не знаю почему назвал группами беседу, да и кого это волнует))
    2000000014, # Русский язык
    2000000018, # Обществознание
    2000000017, # Физика
    2000000015, # История
    2000000016, # Биология
    2000000019, # Английский язык
]

# учителя
ids_teachers = [
    159523091, # Назиля (Русский язык)
    37066446, # Диляра (Обществознание)
    88864448, # Анвар (Физика)
    105722192, # Оля (История)
    241310331, # Антонина (Биология)
    44618787, # Регина(Английский язык)
    333017994, # Равиль
    23526696, # Альберт
    504785497, # Санчай
]
# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////// КОНЕЦ МАССИВОВ С ID БЕСЕД И УЧИТЕЛЕЙ /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////// ФУНКЦИИ /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


# Вывод сообщений
def send_message(peer_id, message):
    vk.messages.send(
        peer_id=peer_id,
        message=message,
        random_id=get_random_id(),
    )

# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////// НАЧАЛО ФУНКЦИЙ ПРИЗЫВА /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
def prizyv():
    members = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(
        peer_id = peer_id,
    )['items']

    members_ids = [member['member_id'] for member in members if member['member_id'] > 0]

    message = 'Призыв!'
    for member_id in members_ids:
        message += f'[id{member_id}|#]'

    send_message(peer_id, message)


def prizyv_morning():
    members = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(
        peer_id,
    )['items']

    members_ids = [member['member_id'] for member in members if member['member_id'] > 0]

    message = 'Доброе утро! Напоминаю вам что сегодня будет вебинар. Всем хорошего дня!!!'
    for member_id in members_ids:
        message += f'[id{member_id}|#]'
    for i in range(len(ids_group)):
        send_message(ids_group[i], message)

# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////// КОНЕЦ ФУНКЦИЙ ПРИЗЫВА /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////





# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Планировщик по воскресеньям /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

# теги: rus, eng, phys, bio, history, obsch
# ЧАСОВОЙ ПОЯС -3
def scheduler():
    schedule.every().tuesday.at("01:05").do(prizyv_morning)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        sleep(1)  # Выберите оптимальное значение под свои задачи планировщика

# Создаём и запускаем планировщик в отдельном потоке
t = Thread(target=scheduler)
t.start()


# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Конец планировщика /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////// РЕГИСТРАЦИЯ БОТА /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


accessToken = 'token' # токен
groupId = id  # id группы в котором находится бот

vkBotSession = VkApi(token=accessToken)
longPoll = VkBotLongPoll(vkBotSession, groupId)
vk = vkBotSession.get_api()


# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////// КОНЕЦ РЕГИСТРАЦИИ БОТА /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////// САМА РАБОТА БОТА В БЕСЕДАХ /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
while True:
    try:
        for event in longPoll.listen():
            if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
                """
                Если бот не отвечает на сообщения из беседы, то выдайте ему права
                на чтение всей переписки, а лучше сразу права администратора,
                потому что они нужны для функции prizyv.
                """
                from_id = event.obj['from_id']  # id пользователя, который отправил сообщение
                peer_id = event.obj['peer_id']  # peer_id беседы или ЛС, откуда пришло сообщение

                # lower - это метод приведения к нижнему регистру. Для регистронезависимости.
                message = event.obj['text'].lower()

                # message теперь в нижнем регистре, поэтому все проверки делаем тоже в нижнем регистре
                # теги: rus, eng, phys, bio, history, obsch
                if ('крут' in message) and message != 'полностью согласен! реально круто ':
                    send_message(peer_id, 'О да, это точно круто! B-)')
                elif "призыв!" in message and (from_id in ids_teachers):
                    prizyv()
    except Exception as E:
        time.sleep(1)
#//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, не задавайте сразу несколько вопросов.

Comment: Опять Вы токен оставили в коде.

Comment: Пожалуйста, смените токен :) Вы столько раз его компрометировали, что я действительно волнуюсь за Вас.

Comment: Извиняюсь)))) ахахха

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы отправить сообщение во все беседы, просто оберните тело функции в цикл `for`, передав для итерации список с `peer_id`.

***Пример:***

```py
...
def prizyv_morning(ids: list) -> None:
    for peer_id in ids:
        members = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(
            peer_id,
        )['items']

        members_ids = [member['member_id'] for member in members if member['member_id'] > 0]

        message = 'Доброе утро! Напоминаю вам, что сегодня будет вебинар. Всем хорошего дня!!!'
        for member_id in members_ids:
            message += f'[id{member_id}|#]'

        send_message(peer_id, message)


def scheduler() -> None:
    schedule.every().tuesday.at('01:05').do(prizyv_morning, conversation_ids)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        sleep(1)  # Выберите оптимальное значение
...
```

Comment: Не знаете почему сообщения дублируются?

Comment: @WazzzUp У меня ничего не дублируется. Может у Вас просто 2 процесса бота?

Comment: да было 2 процесса, извините)

Comment: как я понимаю нужно вместо for peer_id in ids поставить for peer_id in ids_group если у меня айди групп хранится в массиве ids_group

Comment: @WazzzUp Нет. Подставьте `ids_group` вместо `conversation_ids` в функции `scheduler`

Comment: ок а если мне нужно вызвать подобную функцию, только чтобы он реагировал на сообщение "общий призыв" и тогда он во все беседы отправлял упоминания? я код поисправлял ничего не получилось

Comment: @WazzzUp Функция `prizyv_morning` принимает список с беседами (точнее, с их `peer_id`) и отправляет упоминания во все беседы из списка. Она универсальна. Выберите нужные `peer_id`, добавьте их в список и передайте в функцию. В примере я создаю задачу запуска этой функции, которой будет передан список `conversation_ids`.